# When growing a company, is it more important to build a culture or  establish processes?

Tags: culture

The goal is to have sustained growth and sustained delivery of high-quality products.

Comment: Wouldn't this question fit better at [OnStartups](http://answers.onstartups.com/)?

Comment: The priorities for "growing a company" are off topic for a site about Project Management. But with a bit with more detail, you're question is perfectly suited to http://answers.onstartups.com.

Comment: @Robert: It is [answers.onstartups.com](http://answers.onstartups.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Of course a culture is more important.

Here is an analogy:

What would you prefer?

- A city with lots of traffic rules and rowdy drivers or;
- Really careful responsible drivers with a couple of broken signal lights that don’t work at all.

You can have all the signals you want but if the drivers are rowdy there WILL be accidents.

On the other hand if you have responsible drivers, they will drive slowly around crossings and turns even with the signal lights turned off.

The same is true with culture; a strong culture and having responsible people is way more important than a full proof process.

A strong culture and kickass talent will often fill up gaps in a weak process, but you cannot make 10 clueless chumps without any purpose and meaning do the job of one kickass employee with a strong purpose, meaning, **culture** and **competence**.

Answer (score 0):

I would say building the culture is more important.

The nuances of a process are likely to be driven in part by the behavior and attitudes instilled by the culture.